# What's the difference between declaring the variable before or after 'AS'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I found my friend's query like this.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployeeTakeHomePay]
    @erCode VARCHAR(50) ,
    @payCycCode VARCHAR(50) ,
    @pyYear SMALLINT ,
    @pyMonth TINYINT ,
    @pyPrd SMALLINT ,
    @seq INT
AS 
    DECLARE @prdStartDate DATETIME
    BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 0
            *
    INTO    #molohok
    FROM    dbo.PYTRX_TakeHomePayWorkfile
    WHERE   ErCode = @erCode
            AND PayCycCode = @payCycCode
            AND PYYear = @pyYear
            AND PYMonth = @pyMonth
            AND PYPrd = @pyPrd
            AND Seq = @seq
```

There are variables before and after 'AS' as well. What's the difference between declaring the variables before and after 'AS'?

Comment: The ones before are parameters to the stored procedure...

Comment: Those before `AS` are parameters, and that one after `AS` is a variable declared in the SP body and accessible only by the SP itself.

Comment: That query looks pretty odd too; a parametrised `TOP 0` query? The result would be the same whether of not the query is parametrised.

Comment: @Larnu There's a bunch of query actually, but i didn't copy them all.

Comment: That doesn't actually change my point about the parametrised `TOP 0` though, @riachan .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parameters are before AS, and variables are in the declaration body which is after AS

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployeeTakeHomePay]
    <procedure parameters>
AS 
    <local variables>
```

[see official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

The "variables" before the `as` are parameters to the stored procedure.

Parameters are "variables" that are provided when the stored procedure is called.  So this stored procedure requires six parameters.  Parameters can be optional.

The "variables" after the `as` are declared local variables for use when the stored procedure is running.  Actually, `declare` can be used in any programming block.

Note that a stored procedure can accept multiple statements.  However, I *always* put the body of the stored procedure in its own `begin`/`end` block.  I also put parentheses around the parameters to the procedure.

So, I would write this as:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].GetEmployeeTakeHomePay (
    @erCode VARCHAR(50) ,
    @payCycCode VARCHAR(50) ,
    @pyYear SMALLINT ,
    @pyMonth TINYINT ,
    @pyPrd SMALLINT ,
    @seq INT
) AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @prdStartDate DATETIME;

    . . . 
END;  -- GetEmployeeTakeHomePay
```